# Adding a number to iPhone or Android phone contact list in a non-native application

Tags: java, javascript, android, iphone, html

I need to programatically add a number into my contact list in iPhone or Android phone. I'm writing my code in Java and I also use javascript and HTML5. So far, whatever solution I found is for a native app. Does anyone has any solution which can be use in a non native app?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by non native app?

Comment: I mean without using xcode for iPhone for example. I want to do it via the browser using Javascript or etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone and Android browsers do not have access to their respective contacts list. You will have to use a native application to accomplish this.